# how to pick up new updated file from rsync log

Tags: rsync

I always use rsync command for backup below.

```
$ rsync -auvvz source_dir destination_dir
```

To increase verbosity, I use option `v`.
But, in this case, there is too many logs to pick up new updated file log at console.

ex)

```
hgoe/foo/foo/test1 is uptodate
hgoe/foo/foo/test2 <- I want to pick up logs like this.
hgoe/foo/foo/test3 is uptodate
```

How to pick up the logs ?

Comment: So?
Does it not solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but working hack,

```
rsync -auvvz source_dir destination_dir| grep -vE '(sending incremental file list|delta-transmission disabled| is uptodate|total: matches=| bytes/sec| speedup is |^$)'
```

**grep -v** corresponds to the --invert-match option,

while **-E**, to the --extended-regexp one

**^$** removes a blank line,

the other patterns are all included in the default output for rsync -auvvz